# Forcing Windows 10 to sync account settings

Tags: windows-10, sync, user-accounts, onedrive

Today I wanted to ask if there is any way to force settings synchronization in Windows 10?
Last day I decided to reinstall my Windows 10, but after installing new instance Windows won't ask me if I want to get my settings from onedrive account (I was installing Windows 10 Pro N version).

I still have my old Windows 10 instance on old HDD (I bought new SSD), so I can force old OS to upload settings to the cloud, and then try to get it back on new Windows.

Thanks for help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may recreate Windows 10 account.
One way of doing it:

1. Open `cmd.exe` ( <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, *"Command Prompt (Admin)"* ), type `net user Administrator /active:yes`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Sign in as Administrator (<kbd>Win</kbd>, click current user avatar, *"sign out"*, sign in as admin).
3. Delete user that fails to sync, e.g. via *Settings*. **Your data and settings will be removed!**
4. Add new user within **Administrators** group in *Settings* or this way:

   1. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, `control userpasswords2`.
   2. Add new user (via Microsoft account or create local user if you want custom name for your user folder).
   3. Add user to Administrators group in user properties.
5. Sign in with new user, bind to Microsoft account in *Settings* for local users.
6. Turn off Administrator account in `cmd.exe`: `net user Administrator /active:no`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, while upgrading my HDD. I was not sure on old HDD sync is upto date. Here are the steps I did,

1. Updated onedrive desktop app from Microsoft.
2. Right click on One drive quick launch icon on your taskbar, and select "View online"
   [image]
3. It will open Onedrive content in your browser as below,
   [image]

you can resync your desktop folder contents again, and is upto date. This include your current settings also.

4. Replace your new HDD, install latest Onedrive desktop app, and do the same process again.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not what I wanted to achieve. I wanted to sync system settings (control panel settings, etc.), but when I contacted MS support they told me that it's not currently supported in Windows 10.